# Finding a vector that's perpendicular to another given vector?

Tags: vectors, inner-products

So I have the vector

$\vec{u}=\left<0.82,6.45,-1.07\right>$

and I need to find a vector $\vec{v}$ that's perpendicular to this one. The given hint is that I need to use "projection onto $\vec{u}$", which I presume is referring to the vector projection, to find $\vec{v}$. I don't see how this hint, or any other way, could help me find such a vector.

Comment: Pick an arbitrary vector and subtract its projection onto $\vec{u}$.

Comment: Presumably you want a non-zero vector $v$?

Comment: @carmichael561 yes

Comment: @MichaelBurr so I can pick, say, $$\vec{k}=\left<1,1,1\right>,$$ then calculate $proj^k_u=\displaystyle\frac{\vec{k}\cdot\vec{u}}{\left|\vec{k}\right|} \frac{\vec{k}}{\left|\vec{k}\right|}$?

Comment: And make sure to subtract that from $\vec{k}$.  Give it a try and see what happens!

Comment: @MichaelBurr I've tried that, and when I tested the resulting vector after the subtraction by computing its dot product with $\vec{u}$, I get a non-zero answer, which indicates that the resulting vector isn't perpendicular to $\vec{u}$

Comment: Actually, it has worked, it's just that the dot product is infinitesimally small that it might as well have been 0 ($-4.4409e(-16)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any non-zero vector $\vec u=\langle a,b,c \rangle$, at least two of $\langle 0,c,-b \rangle$, $\langle -c,0,a \rangle$ and $\langle b,-a,0 \rangle$ are also non-zero. (These are the cross products with the standard basis vectors.) You can easily verify that all three are orthogonal to $\vec u$.

However, the hint wants you to use projection onto $\vec u$, so you basically need to perform a step of the Gram-Schmidt process: pick any non-zero vector $\vec v$ that’s not a multiple of $\vec u$, compute its projection onto $\vec u$ and then subtract that from $\vec v$. What’s left—the orthogonal *rejection* of $\vec v$ from $\vec u$—is orthogonal to $\vec u$. I.e., compute $$\vec v - {\vec v\cdot \vec u \over \vec u\cdot\vec u}\vec u.$$

Answer (score 3):

$\vec{v}(a,b,c)\perp\vec{u}$ says $0.82a+6.45b-1.07c=0.$

Now, take $c=0$, $b=-0.82$ and $a=6.45.$

Answer (score 1):

Every 3D vector $\vec{v}=\left<a,b,c\right>$ which is peerpendicular to $\vec{u}=\left<0.82,6.45,-1.07\right>$ have the property $u.v=0$ so 
$$0.82a+6.45b-1.07c=0$$
this is the equation of a plane and also $c=\frac{0.82a+6.45b}{1.07}$, then with arbitrary $a$ and $b$ you can find $c$ and hence $v$.